# Problem detection in reaction procedure

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

We all know that oxidation of secondary alcohols leads to ketones. So, with that logic, in order to form acetone $CH_3-CO-CH_3$ through oxidation, we need a secondary alcohol like *isopropyl alcohol*. Now there is a problem I am trying to figure out, where I need to identify each reactants + reactions involved.

It is given that *acetone* is the end product , now with that information I need to traverse backwards/in backward direction and determine *A, B and C*. First let me mention the reaction procedure:

$A+HI\rightarrow B+KOH\rightarrow C+[O]\rightarrow Acetone$

Now, it is quite clear that *C* represents *isopropyl alcohol* (oxidation of secondary alcohols). Now, *isopropyl* alcohol has *OH* group in the second carbon atom, and that must have come from *KOH*. Also, since C (as a product) has 3 carbon atoms, hence *B* must also have 3 carbon atoms. Now, what is confusing me is this part:

$A+HI\rightarrow B+KOH$

Since, in the reactant side there is *I (iodine)* group, hence, *B (as a product)* must have *iodine* in it. But considering *C*, there is no *iodine (I)* group in it, so does it mean that *I* group was substituted by *OH* group? Because, normally, i have seen $OH$ group being substituted by *I* group. Also, I don't think that *A* will be alcohol (because *C* already is an alcohol), moreover it is quite apparent that even *A* must have 3 carbon atoms...or does it not? (I am not sure). Also, considering *B*, it is sure to have *I* group on second carbon atom. Is my approach correct? (Please correct me if I am wrong). What according to you should be *A* and *B*?

Comment: Your thoughts on the identity of B and C are correct. How would concentrated HI react with an alkene?

Comment: Oh yeah, it works, Markonikoff's rule into play!